# How to extract the result of a db.command query from JSON inside a custom javascript function in OrientDB

Tags: javascript, json, orientdb, orientdb2.2

I have this SQL code in this custom javascript.

> var inLinkNodes = db.command('sql','SELECT in() FROM node where @rid = ' + relateNode);

.

> return inLinkNodes;

when I return this variable, I get the following output:

Output:
 

[

    {

           "@type": "d",

        "@rid": "#-2:0",

        "@version": 0,

        "in": [

            "#17:9"

        ],

        "@fieldTypes": "in=z"

    }

]

## I want only "#17:9" as the output.

I tried this following command:

> return inLinkNodes[0].getRecord().field( "in" );

but this gives this following output:

> [
>    
>    {
>       
>     "@type": "d",
>     
>       "@rid": "#17:9",
>    
>        "@version": 2,
>     
>       "@class": "node",
>     
>       "out_isLinkedTo": [
>      
>          "#13:25"
>      
>      ],
>         
>   "@fieldTypes": "out_isLinkedTo=g"
>   
>     }
>   
> ]

How to extract only "#17:9" as a string output?

Comment: hello, can you mark it as resolved? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var inLinkNodes = db.command('sql','select expand(@this.exclude('@type','@rid','@version','@class')) from (SELECT in() FROM node where @rid = ' + relateNode + ')');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
var inLinkNodes = db.command('sql','SELECT in().@rid FROM ' + relateNode);
```

Hope it helps !